# Switch value of variables using double pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I got a problem with my pointer program, it should use double pointers to switch the value of double values x and y. I am pretty new to pointers and I am not able to accomplish that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/*
todo
implement switch_pp(**a,**b)
switch the content of a,b using double pointers
Only switch the values all pointer addresses must remain the same! 
*/

 void switch_pp(double** a,double** b){
   double valueOfA = **a;
   double valueOfB = **b;
   *a = &valueOfB;
   *b = &valueOfA;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    double x = 14.435,y = 4.435; //needs to work with these parameters
    double *ptr_x = &x, *ptr_y= &y;

    printf("Swapping x and y\n");
    printf("X -> address: %p | value: %f || Y-> address: %p | value: %f\n", x,x,y,y);
    switch_pp(&ptr_x,&ptr_y);
    printf("Done swapping x and y\n");
    printf("X -> address: %p | value: %f || Y-> address: %p | value: %f\n", x,x,y,y);
    return 0;
 }
```

The output is:

```
Swapping x and y
X -> address: A3D70A3D | value: -0.000000 || Y-> address: 4011BD70 | value: 4.435000
Done swapping x and y
X -> address: A3D70A3D | value: -0.000000 || Y-> address: 4011BD70 | value: 4.435000

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.016 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Okay now I rewrote my code still the values of x,y won 't swap! although I reference *a = &ValueOfB; But as far as I understood &ptr_x -> ptr_x -> x so if I write *a = &ValueOfB I could also substitute *a with ptr_x so I can further substitute to ptr_x = &y! which should work

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings, and pay attention to them.  It should be complaining about mismatched types between your function's parameters and its actual arguments.

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the *exact* output you got from exactly *one* run? Please double check.

Comment: To printf addresses you need to pass addresses. You pass doubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you had orignally doesn't work because you pass a `double *` to a function that expects a `double **`.  The types aren't compatible, and attempting to use them that way results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

With your edit, it still won't work because `ptr_x` and `ptr_y` are modified to contain the address of the variables `valueOfA` and `valueOfB` inside of `switch_pp`.  When the function returns, those variables are out of scope, so attempting to dereference those pointers again results in undefined behavior.

You would only need a double pointer (i.e. a pointer to a pointer) if you are swapping pointers.  But you aren't swapping pointers, you're swapping values of type `double`.  So just pass the addresses of each and swap what each one points to:

```
void swap(double *a, double *b)
{
    double tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
swap(&a, &b);
```

EDIT:

If you really need to pass a pointer-to-pointer, then do this:

```
void swap(double **a, double **b)
{
    double tmp = **a;
    **a = **b;
    **b = tmp;
}
```

EDIT2:

The addresses are not changing, but it might appear that way because you're not printing them correctly:

```
printf("X -> address: %p | value: %f || Y-> address: %p | value: %f\n", x,x,y,y);
```

Here, you're passing a `double` to the `%p` format specifier which expects a `void *`.  You want this instead:

```
printf("X -> address: %p | value: %f || Y-> address: %p | value: %f\n", (void *)ptr_x,x,(void *)ptr_y,y);
```

Note that this is one of the rare time you actually need to cast a pointer to a `void *`.

Comment: I know that it works that way but swap needs to be in this form:

void swap(double **a, double **b){...} this is the challange !

Comment: okay now the value swaps but so do the addresses of the pointers. How can I store **a on the exact same spot **b was stored?

Comment: @Raavgo No, the addresses are not swapped.  You're printing the addresses wrong.

Comment: Yes now it works! Thank you very much!
so %p expects a void pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Look at what you're doing here:

> `switch_pp(&x,&y);`

and compare that to your `swap` function:

> `void switch_pp(double** a,double** b)`

What would you say the type of `&x` is?

Comment: This would better suit as comment.

Comment: @alk There's a long history of [hand holding in answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255896/643383) to obvious homework questions. What I've written is as close as one might get to answering the question without spelling it out for the OP, and I think that's the most appropriate way to answer this kind of question.

Comment: Well, fair enough, make sense, yes.

Comment: Well no it is no homework question, but nvm. 
I know &x is the space *x points to but how can I switch the values of x,y using double pointers.

Comment: @Raavgo In your code, `x` is a `double`, not a pointer to anything. `&x` is not "the space that `x` points to", but rather the address of `x`, so it's type is `double*`. As far as it being a homework question, it's certainly at least in the same vein -- you're trying to get your head around pointers, and while it's tempting to just get the answer, it'll stick with you much better if you figure it out yourself. You're almost there -- keep at it!

Comment: yes I do know that, well I remembered it when you told me.
So I got some doubles I wanna switch if I define a ptr_x = &x; I can get a double pointer by typing &ptr_x right? 
now I got a double pointer suitable for swap(a,b) but now I wanna change the variables of x and this is the pointer structur:
 &ptr_x -> ptr_x -> x
but now I just can copy the pointers but how do I access the values?

Comment: @Raavgo I guess the question is: do you want to swap the values of `x` and `y` or do you want to leave those values right where they are and swap pointers to those values? Right now your `main` function expects the former, but your `swap` function is set up to do the latter.

Comment: @Caleb I want to switch the values but the address of x and y needs to remain the same! If I simply switch x,y they get a new address! So if I could access the values of the variables that &ptr_x or &ptr_y points to I could just refer these values to their new location. Is there a way to store valueof(&ptr_x) into a variable for example into double bufferValue

Comment: @Raavgo Look at `swap` then. Parameters `a` and `b` are `double **`, or in words, "a pointer to a pointer to a double." If you want to switch the doubles themselves, you need to dereference those pointers twice (like: `**a` instead of `*a`), and you need to pass the pointers to pointers to doubles when you call `swap`. If you have `double x; double *ptr_x;` you can say `ptr_x = &x;` and you can likewise say `double **ptr_ptr_x = &ptr_x;`.

Comment: Usually, though, when a function takes an argument like `double **` in C, it's because the function wants to modify the pointer, not the `double`, so it's hard to see the point in passing `double **` in the case of your `swap` function.

Comment: You're still changing the pointer rather than the value. What you want is `**a = valueOfB; **b = valueOfA;`.